# Current directory appended to windows cmd passed in "parameter" causing invalid argument

Tags: windows, cmd, arguments

I am trying to run a gimp batch command in windows cmd.

```
 "C:\Program Files (x86)\GIMP-2.0\bin\gimp-console-2.6.exe" -i -b --verbose "(maketemplates \"C:\\autocovers\\sample\")" -b "(gimp-quit 0)"
```

I get the following:
GIMP-Error: Opening 'C:\Users\IOANNIS(maketemlpates "C:\autocovers\sample")' failed: Invalid argument

The argument does indeed seem invalid as it has the current directory appended to it! Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have GIMP installed on my Windows test boxes, so I can't test this, but I suspect that the `--verbose` option might be causing the issue.

The option `-b` expects an argument, but in your command-line you placed the option `--verbose` *between* `-b` and its argument, which would make the string `--verbose` the argument of `-b`. That leaves the intended argument `"(maketemplates \"C:\\autocovers\\sample\")"` as a non-option parameter. As [documented](http://www.gimp.org/man/gimp.html), `gimp-console` considers all non-option parameters as file names.

Change your command-line from

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\GIMP-2.0\bin\gimp-console-2.6.exe" -i -b --verbose "(maketemplates \"C:\\autocovers\\sample\")" -b "(gimp-quit 0)"</code>
```

to

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\GIMP-2.0\bin\gimp-console-2.6.exe" --verbose -i -b "(maketemplates \"C:\\autocovers\\sample\")" -b "(gimp-quit 0)"</code>
```

and your problem should go away.